# Modify Time Utility Component in WebRatio

Tags: data-modeling

I am new to using WebRatio and IFML. I need to build a small web application where at a certain point it is necessary to do some validation based on the timestamp a user provides. This timestamp should be between the range of minimum 24hours from now and maximum 14 days.

I hoped to find a way to adapt the values passed from a Time Utility component, add 24 hours or 14 days to it and then use a Compare Validation Rule to validate what the user has entered.

Can someone please explain how I can accomplish my goal here?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to make this validation is to model in the form two hidden fields containing the minimum and maximum value allowed for the timestamp. In this way you can model on the timestamp field two Compare Validation Rules. Each Compare Validation Rule uses the Value Field property filled in with one of the hidden field. So, at the end, the validations on the field express these conditions

- timestamp field greater than minimum timestamp
- timestamp field lower than maximum timestamp

To fill the hidden fields with the correct value, given the current timestamp, you can use the **Dates Function** component. You can download it from the [WebRatio Addons](https://www.webratio.com/store/item-details/dates-function-)